# Showing next available dates with 24h margin with Angular and MomentJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs

I'm trying to display an array of possible delivery dates using AngularJS and MomentJS.
The issue is that it needs to meet certain conditions: **Delivery dates are only Monday, Wednesday and Fridays**.

Also, when the page loads, it recognizes the current date and it will only display **the next available date that is minimum 24h away** (e.g., if I load the page on a Sunday at 1pm, the first available date will be Wednesday, as Monday doesn't meet the 24h margin).

So far I could only think if dealing with the issue doing conditionals for every day of the week, but I'm pretty sure there has to be a neater way of dealing with it.

Here's what I did so far:

```
$scope.today = moment();

$scope.$watch('today', function () {
    if ($scope.today = moment().day('Sunday')){
      $scope.nextdateone = moment().add(3, 'd');
      $scope.nextdatetwo = moment().add(5, 'd');
      $scope.nextdatethree = moment().add(8, 'd');
      $scope.nextdatefour = moment().add(10, 'd');
    }
    else if ($scope.today = moment().day('Monday')){
      $scope.nextdateone = moment().add(2, 'd');
      $scope.nextdatetwo = moment().add(4, 'd');
      $scope.nextdatethree = moment().add(7, 'd');
      $scope.nextdatefour = moment().add(9, 'd');
    }
    else if ...
});
```

This was the logic I came up with, but it doesn't really work as of now...

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delivery dates "Monday, Wednesday and Fridays", which (according to http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) you can represent as 1, 3 and 5.

So I would create a array with those dates, and then given the current day I would iterate that array of delivery dates to find the most suitable one... something like this:

```
const deliveryDates = [1, 3, 5];

const getDeliveryDate = (today) => {
    let deliveryIndex = -1;

    deliveryDates.some((date, index) => {
        // If today is a delivery date, then schedule for the next delivery
        if (today === date) {
            deliveryIndex = index + 1;
            return true;
        }

        // If today is before the current delivery date, store it
        if (today < date) {
            deliveryIndex = index;
            return true;
        }
    });

    // If delivery date is out of bounds, return the first delivery date   
    return deliveryIndex === deliveryDates.length || deliveryIndex === -1 ? 0 : deliveryIndex;
};

const getNextDelivery = (today) => {
    return deliveryDates[getDeliveryDate(today)];
};

console.log(moment().day(getNextDelivery(moment().day())));
```

You can check a working example here:
https://jsbin.com/jawexafiji/edit?js,console